# Problems with Generic Repository Pattern and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, repository-pattern

There are a large number of examples on how to use the Generic Repository Pattern over Entitry Framework but none ever go into great detail.  More often than not the example they use for accessing data from a webapi is a one to one mapping to the model.

For Eg. Get a single model object `_carRepository<Car>.Get(id);` or get all cars `_carRepository<Car>.GetAll();`

The way I have it implemented is in seperate layers like below:

**Controller -> Service Layer -> Repository Layer -> DataAccess**

I have my service layer using AutoMapper where I map from the model(entity) to a DTO and that gets returned to the controller who returns that.

The issue that I cant get my head around is how do I return an object from the repository layer which isnt of type < T>.

Eg.  I want to return some data for a grid lets say a combination of multipe entities like a customers last number of purchases.  Am I supposed to pass the Customer, Product, Orders repository into the service and make multiple calls to the database and aggregate?  Or I was thinking in the cutomers repository just make a method which returns like a view dto of sorts already aggreating the data where it does a linq query and projects to this dto.  The issue I have is that I'm sure my repository shouldnt know about dto's?

Would appreciate anyone who has thoughts on the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Most MVC guides intoroduce the ida of a "viewmodel" for this.... which tells me that MVC is not as simple as it sounds.

Answer (score 4):

In short, I don't ever recommend using the Generic Repository (anti)pattern. The trouble is that it ends up being far too restrictive and inefficient. Methods like `GetAll()` serve only to end up materializing entire tables into memory. They don't accommodate things like projection (essentially what you are looking for) as well as eager loading related data, filtering, sorting, or things like supporting pagination.

The way I recommend looking at repositories is as a one-to-one supplier of data for a Controller in the MVC pattern. If you have a CarController you have a CarRepository to serve all data for that controller. If you break it down to CarController and AddCarController then similarly you can build repositories to serve each of these. These repositories are not Generic in that they don't just serve Car entities, but any and all entities from the DbContext that this controller  (or service) needs rather than trying to marry repositories to a specific entity. This gives them only one concern for their existance, so a CarController only needs to worry about primarily one repository, and that repository only has to worry about serving that controller. (Rather than every controller that might want information about a Car)

Regarding using a Service between the controller and repository, I would only suggest this if there is a distinct requirement to provide that separation. For example, if you want to support both an MVC controller and a public facing WebAPI and you want the inputs and outputs provided to these to be 100% consistent. The data transported from Service to Consumer (Controllers, etc.) would be DTOs. This adds the complexity of needing to send details like sorting, pagination, and filtering etc. from the consumer to the service.

Removing the service can make interacting with the repository a lot easier, and you can leverage projection to populate the DTOs/view models actually sent to the view via the controller actions/endpoints. The way I facilitate this is leveraging `IQueryable<TEntity>` in the repository. This lets the repository handle low level filtering/rules if necessary and lets the consumer (controller) handle determining how it wants to consume the data.

For example if we have a CarController with a CarRepository and CarRepository has a method:

```
public IQueryable<Car> GetCars(bool includeInactive = false)
{
    var query = _context.Cars.AsQueryable();
    if (!includeInactive)
        query = query.Where(x => x.IsActive);
    return query;
}
```

When it comes time for the controller to request cars from the repository, it has full control over how to consume it:

```
 var cars = await CarRepository.GetCars()
     .Where(x => x.Make == make && x.Model == model)
     .OrderBy(x => x.ModelYear)
     .Select(x => new CarSummary
     {
         Make = x.Make,
         Model = x.Model,
         ModelYear = x.ModelYear,
         Color = x.Color,
         Features = x.Features.Select(...)
     }.Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber-1))
     .Take(pageSize)
     .ToListAsync();
```

The controller has full control over how the data should come back including whether to run an async query or synchronous one all without adding any complexity to the repository. So here we can project (`Select`, or leverage Automapper and `ProjectTo`) to get whatever data we need from the entities and their related data. This leads to building far faster and memory/network efficient queries because the projections only worry about the data the end consumer actually needs. When we want to load an entity and its relations to perform an update, we can fetch the entity and eager load the related data we need to inspect/validate/update. Eager loading data is faster than lazy loading, but both use a fair bit of memory so we don't want to be serializing and transmitting entire object graphs. However, when doing an update we are typically only dealing with a single top-level object at a time.

The question then becomes "Why use a repository then?" The repository provides a nice abstraction for unit testing, and it can help standardize core rules you want in the system such as Active/Inactive (soft delete) and things like authorization in systems using multi-tenancy or otherwise having distinct access controls for the current user as to what data they should ever be able to see. If you don't have either of these requirements, then there isn't really much point to using a repository at all. The DbContext and it's DbSets essentially serve that role.

If you do have plans for multiple consumers, then the repository remains the same but the above consuming code happens in the Service, returning the DTO/ViewModel. This means that your controller will need to package and transmit standardized requests to the service or parameters covering whether it expects any sorting, pagination, etc. Again, I wouldn't recommend taking on that overhead and complexity unless there is a very real requirement justifying it. It just serves to make the code harder to work with.

Comment: I have to say - I've read this and agree with everything you have outlined.  Since implmenting the generic repository pattern Ive had nothing but questions regarding the validity of it.

Also not to mention the amount of extra code files required which are somewhat pretty much empty.

Thank you for taking the time to write this up...!

Comment: Doesn't it have disadvantages to expose `IQueryable`?

Comment: The main argument against exposing `IQueryable` is to try and abstract EF away from the business logic. There is a cost in trying to do this, either in less efficient querying, or a lot more code & complexity to try and keeping some of the efficiency that EF querying can do. Common attempts I see to abstract EF by using things like passing expressions into repository calls still end up having to conform to EF-isms. IMO if you decide to use EF then it's best to embrace and trust it rather than trying to abstract it. Abstracting just leads to the issues that abstracting was an exit option for.

Comment: If you return the `IQueryable<>` and you delegate the query to the Controller, you have some disadvantages:

1. You can not write an Unit Test for that query. So how do you know if that works? You are forced to test the entire Controller.

2. Returning an `IQueryable<>` forces you to duplicate the query that you need in multiple points of your code.

I mean, probably I prefer to encapsulate queries and test it with an Unit Test to catch regression. What you think? :)

Comment: `IQueryable` enables testing, the mocked repository returns a List of known data, or a wrapped list if you want to perform async operations. The repository still applies base filtering. If there are multiple calls that need the identical query then can still used a shared method to build it.  The benefits that `IQueryable` bring are the ability to optimize the query to each consumer's needs without a lot of similar, but not identical methods in a centralized repository, or worse, repository methods that have to serve the lowest common denominator. (everyone is as fast as the slowest option)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be complete answer but few things while working with Generic Repository.

Assumption I made that your generic repository return type of T and T is the entity.

Following is not exact interface but based on your question.

```
public class IRepository<T>
{
    T Get(int Id);
    IEnumrable<T> GetAll();
}
```

So most of the scenario above will suffice the thing.

Now let's assume that you have requirement that will only return specific attribute of T or partial of T.

- Generic repository implementation never say that you don't need any extra or extended repository.
- So you can do like this.

```
public interface ICarRepository : IRepository<Car>
{
    IList<int> GetIds();
    IList<string> GetAllModels();
    bool IsActiveInProduction(int carId);
}
```

Implement above just like you have implemented IRepository for EF core. Inject this in your services and Use ICarRepository instead of IRepository
for your development.

Note: This is personal preference but for large project GenericRepository become issue sometime or may not completely fit but Repository is useful pattern and it overall depends on how you use it.

#### Update 1

In Car Repository if you want to return some other DTO but make sure it related to Car Entity otherwise it is not reponsibility of Repo layer.

```
public interface ICarRepository : IRepository<Car>
{
    IList<int> GetIds();
    IList<string> GetAllModels();
    bool IsActiveInProduction(int carId);
    MyDto GetMyDto(int carId); // MyDto is just for explanation.
}
```

Comment: I apologise I have implemented as you have displayed I should be clear and I will edit my OP.  I do have a generic repository and a car repository on top of that which I inject into the service layer.  But my question will still remain.... how do I pass back a complex aggregate view back to the service layer.

Comment: What is meaning of complex ? Is it related to only Car Entity or other related entity ? If you want to merge result then it is Service Layer responsibility merge result and return DTO.

Comment: Yes that was in my question.  If I have a complex linq query like customer -> orders -> products.  Am I supposed to pass all 3 repositories into the service layer and make seperate calls to get the desired data and then loop these datasets to get it all together or shoudnt i just be able to do a linq query which makes 1 call and project back to a dto?

Comment: If It is Car and its child record then CarRepository is good place. In your case if you have to merge this things then make different call to DB and then produce Dto. I have seen in some place where Generic repository has T property or method that return IQuerable so you can query along with other repository like order.

Comment: Yes I have seen where it returns IQueryable but then it made me think what was the whole purpose of repository pattern.

Comment: There are many things. Like you have repository per Table or per main object like parent object. Also purpose of Repository pattern is to hide your provider so like if you are using EF core or any other ORM, repository provides abstraction over that.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the BaseRespository.cs code that is use that I use as Generic class for entity framework. I inherit this class as parent with my other RepositoryClass.

public class BaseRepository
{
#region Ctor(s)

```
    protected RuhBotEntities RuhBotEntities;

    public BaseRepository(RuhBotEntities entities)
    {
        this.RuhBotEntities = entities;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Protected & Private Members

    protected async Task<T> Get<T>(Guid id) where T : class
    {
        return await this.RuhBotEntities.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    protected IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>(out int totalCount ,bool isDeleted, string searchField = null, string searchTerm = null,
        int? pageIndex = null, int? pageSize = null, string sortBy = null, SortOrder? sortOrder = null) where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> entities = this.RuhBotEntities.Set<T>();

        var sortByProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortBy);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortBy) && sortOrder.HasValue && sortByProperty != null)
        {
            switch (sortByProperty.PropertyType.FullName)
            {
                case "System.Int32":
                    entities = this.RuhBotEntities.Set<T>().Sort<T, int>(sortBy, sortOrder);
                    break;

                case "System.String":
                    entities = this.RuhBotEntities.Set<T>().Sort<T, string>(sortBy, sortOrder);
                    break;
            }
        }

        PropertyInfo[] entityProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        var propertyList = entityProperties.Where(p => p.PropertyType.FullName == "System.String").Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchField))
        {
            entities = entities.Where(string.Format("{0}.Contains(@0)", searchField), searchTerm);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm) && propertyList.Count > 0)
        {
            var searchFieldList = new List<string>();
            propertyList.ForEach(p => searchFieldList.Add(string.Format("{0}.Contains(@0)", p)));
            var propertySearchField = String.Join("||", searchFieldList);

            entities = entities.Where(propertySearchField, searchTerm);
        }

        if (isDeleted)
        {
            entities = entities.Where(string.Format("{0}.Equals(@0)", "IsDeleted"), false);
        }

        totalCount = entities.Count();

        if (pageIndex.HasValue && pageSize.HasValue)
        {
            entities = entities.OrderBy(sortBy).Skip(pageIndex.Value * pageSize.Value).Take(pageSize.Value);
        }

        return entities;
    }

    protected void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        this.RuhBotEntities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public async Task<T> AddIfNotExists<T>(T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class, new()
    {
        var dbSet = this.RuhBotEntities.Set<T>();
        var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Any(predicate) : dbSet.Any();

        return exists ? await dbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate) : dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    protected void Update<T>(T entity, params string[] fieldsExcludedForUpdation) where T : class
    {
        var dbEntityEntry = this.AttachEntity(entity);

        var createdOn = dbEntityEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedOn");
        var createdBy = dbEntityEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedBy");

        if (createdOn != null)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.Property("CreatedOn").IsModified = false;
        }

        if (createdBy != null)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.Property("CreatedBy").IsModified = false;
        }

        if (fieldsExcludedForUpdation != null && fieldsExcludedForUpdation.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var field in fieldsExcludedForUpdation)
            {
                dbEntityEntry.Property(field).IsModified = false;
            }
        }

        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    protected void Delete<T>(Guid id) where T : class
    {
        var entity = this.RuhBotEntities.Set<T>().Find(id);
        this.RuhBotEntities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    protected async Task SaveChanges()
    {
        await this.RuhBotEntities.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private DbEntityEntry AttachEntity(object entity)
    {
        var entry = this.RuhBotEntities.Entry(entity);

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            var set = this.RuhBotEntities.Set(entity.GetType());
            object attachedEntity = set.Find(entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entity));

            if (attachedEntity != null)
            {
                var attachedEntry = this.RuhBotEntities.Entry(attachedEntity);
                attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

                return attachedEntry;
            }
            else
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.RuhBotEntities.Set(entity.GetType()).Attach(entity);
            this.RuhBotEntities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        return entry;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? It's nothing but yet another generic repository.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).