# EF Migrations on Generic Repository

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, repository-pattern

I´m creating a generic Repository with Entity Framework. It looks like this:

```
    public abstract class EntityRepository<TEntity> : IEntityRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
    {
        protected DataContext Context { get; set; }

        protected DbSet<TEntity> EntitySet { get; set; }

        public EntityRepository(DataContext context)
        {
            this.Context = context;
            this.EntitySet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        //CRUD methods omitted for simplicity
}
```

So then I can create a repository that inherits from this one and adds some other functionaly/logic...

```
public class VariationsRepository : EntityRepository<Variation>, IVariationsRepository
```

The problem is that I´m using the code-first approach and when I create a migration no tables are created in the database... How can I make sure that the migrations creates the corresponding tables for each entity that have a repository? (All the models of the application will have the implementation of the generic repository)

Comment: Don't use a generic repository with EF.  See Steve Py's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552613/problems-with-generic-repository-pattern-and-entity-framework

Comment: Whether migrations pick up new tables has nothing to do with a repository pattern. It's *only* determined by EF mappings and their history. Since we can't see these things, this question can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can define each Entity on the method `OnModelCreating` by utilizing a override on the context.

```cs
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext (DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasKey(o => o.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(o => o.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);
    }

}
```

I prefer to config my entities that way, instead of using DataAnnotation attributes.

You can also think "Ok, but if I a have lot of entities this configuration method will be huge".
In this case you can split in many classes like in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20220810022249/https://digitaldrummerj.me/ef-core-split-model-config/).